# How linux command ":>" works?

Tags: linux, streaming

I use command ":>file.log" to truncate file.log to zero length. I got it from the internet, but I do not understand how it works. I think that it copies some stream to a file, but I can't manage to find in manual which stream it uses.

Answer (score 15):

The command isn't `:>` it's just `:`.  In bash (and probably some other shells) it's a built-in no-op command.  The `>` redirects output to a file (truncating it first).  Since `:` has no output, the net result of your command line `: > file.log` just makes `file.log` zero length.

From my local `bash` man page:

```
  : [arguments]
          No  effect;  the command does nothing beyond expanding arguments
          and performing any specified redirections.  A zero exit code  is
          returned.
```

Answer (score 1):

You may even forget the `:` part and just type `>file.log`

It should produce the same result.